# How to iteratively add new node in a linked list in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write a method from Leetcode [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/) that allows two sorted linked lists to be merged (please ignore the fact that I need to add the case where `l2`'s value is greater). So far, my strategy is to create a new linked list called `mergedList` and adding new values iteratively using a while loop:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode temp1 = l1;
        ListNode temp2 = l2;
        ListNode curr = null;
        
        ListNode mergedList = null;
        ListNode testpoint = null;
        
        
        if(l1 == null && l2 == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else if(l1 == null && l2 != null) {
            return l2;
        }
        else if(l1 != null && l2 == null) {
            return l1;
        }
        else if(l1.next == null && l2.next == null) {
            if(l1.val <= l2.val) {
                l1.next = new ListNode(l2.val);
                return l1;
            }
            else {
                l2.next = new ListNode(l1.val);
                return l2;
            }
        }
        
        if(temp1.val <= temp2.val) {
            while(temp1 != null) {
                mergedList = new ListNode(temp1.val);
                testpoint = mergedList;
                while(temp2 != null) {
                    if(temp1.next != null) {
                        if(temp1.val <= temp2.val && temp2.val <= temp1.next.val) {
                            curr = temp2;
                            mergedList.next = new ListNode(temp2.val);
                        }
                    }
                    temp2 = temp2.next;
                }
                temp2 = curr;
                temp1 = temp1.next;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        
        while(testPoint != null) {
            System.out.println(testPoint.val);
            testPoint = testPoint.next;
        }
        
        
        return mergedList;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to print out mergedList using testpoint as a pointer to it, the only value that is printed is the very last value- why? What am I missing that prevents the new linked list from being created properly?

Comment: Have a look at [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). This is definitely one of those cases where debugging will help you find the flaws in your approach. Step through your code, observe the variables and see if the code actually does what you want it to do. This is a valuable skill to learn early on.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- All new node(s) that the second part of your code creates, are either assigned to `mergedList` or to `mergeList.next`, so the list headed by `mergeList` can never have more than 2 nodes. So it is expected you have tests where only one node is printed.
- The inner loop creates nodes with `temp1.val`, but -- except for the initial case -- there is never a node created with `temp2.val`.
- The nested loops are difficult to follow. With `temp2 = curr;` you'll iterate the second list potentially several times. This should not be necessary.

I don't see it is necessary to deal with so many base cases in the first part of your code. Some of those could be dealt with in the more generic, second part of your code.

It is also not necessary to create `temp1` and `temp2` variables. You can use the parameter variables `l1` and `l2`.

Here is one way to make it work:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode mergedList = null, curr = null, tail = null;

        while (l1 != null && l2 != null) { // There are still nodes in both lists
            if (l1.val <= l2.val) { // Grab a node from the first list
                curr = new ListNode(l1.val);
                l1 = l1.next;
            } else { // Grab a node from the second list
                curr = new ListNode(l2.val);
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            if (tail == null) {  // First time only
                mergedList = curr;
            } else {
                tail.next = curr;
            }
            tail = curr; // Keep track of last node in merged list
        }
        // At least one of the input lists has been processed completely.
        // Use the potentially remaining part from the other input list
        if (tail == null) { // One input list was empty
            return l1 != null ? l1 : l2;
        }
        tail.next = l1 != null ? l1 : l2;
        return mergedList;
    }
}
```

It is good practice to not mutate the input lists, but in this case the code challenge allows such mutation, and so it is not necessary to create new nodes: in the above code you can replace the node creation part with just:

```
        if (l1.val <= l2.val) { // Grab a node from the first list
            curr = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        } else { // Grab a node from the second list
            curr = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
```